# How can I use grouping and page breaks to create a 2-sided SSRS badge report? (Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Report Builder)

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, badge

I'm designing an SSRS badge report for Avery 5392 badge stock (6 per page) that will also print each wearer's record ID on the back of their badge.

I've set up RowNumber & RowMod columns in my SELECT statement so that I can filter into my design elements only 3 rows of data per column and control which rows go on the left or right-side report elements, respectively. I've also set up PageNumber as a possible grouping option for page breaks.

Please consider this dummy table as a proxy for the data I'm actually using:

```
CREATE TABLE #Badges (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Badges VALUES
  (100001, 'Anna')
, (100002, 'Bart')
, (100003, 'Cathy')
, (100004, 'Daniel')
, (100005, 'Ericka')
, (100006, 'Fred')
, (100007, 'Gwen')
, (100008, 'Harry')
, (100009, 'Idita')
, (100010, 'Joshi')
, (100011, 'Katie')
, (100012, 'Leo')
, (100013, 'Manuela')
, (100014, 'Nando')
, (100015, 'Olga')
, (100016, 'Park')
, (100017, 'Quang')
, (100018, 'Rhys')
, (100019, 'Sarina')
, (100020, 'Theo')
, (100021, 'Udeyume')
, (100022, 'Victor')
, (100023, 'Wynona')
, (100024, 'Xavier');

SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.RowNumber) + 5) / 6) AS PageNumber
, a.*

FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Name) AS RowNumber
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Name) % 6 AS RowMod
, b.*

FROM #Badges AS b) AS a

DROP TABLE #Badges
```

I have a 4-square of separate report elements (using "Lists" at the moment) that looks a bit like this...

**| List 1 | List 2 |**

**| List 4 | List 3 |**

I need my report elements to display the first 3 rows of **Name** in the left column (*List 1*), then the next 3 rows of **Name** in the right column (*List 2*). Then, on the following page, I need to flip the Mod orientation using the same data to display the first 3 rows of **ID** in the *right* column (*List 3*), then the next 3 rows of **ID** in the *left* column (*List 4*).

Page 1 would look like this...

| Col 1 (List 1) | Col 2 (List 2) |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | Daniel |
| Bart | Ericka |
| Cathy | Fred |

... and page 2 would look like this...

| Col 1 (List 4) | Col 2 (List 3) |
| --- | --- |
| 100004 | 100001 |
| 100005 | 100002 |
| 100006 | 100003 |

Then I want to repeat that process on page 3 and so on.

Comment: Add an outer group that groups by front/back and set a page break "between" in the group properties.

Comment: There aren't 2 rows of data for each wearer to identify as 'front data' and 'back data'. Just a single row per person. I'm using the same Dataset for all 4 data regions. Are you suggesting I use separate Datasets?

Comment: Probably easier if you share a sample of your dataset output and your current report design. It might mean refactoring the data slightly, hard to tell without seeing more. I would have probably opted to use a single matrix rather than two tables but gain, there might be a good reason you did this that isn't visible until I see the data and design.

Comment: I'm open to refactoring the data, but unfortunately I can't share a sample of this information. Separate matrices were used because this is the only way I've found from my research that is supposed to allow for the second page of information to display the same people from the previous page with the columns flipped. Using a single matrix with this technique complains of inner members. It may just be that this has to be done a completely different way than is the approach I'm trying for or that it's just not possible.

Comment: You dont need to share a sample of your real info, just as long as it has the same structure. Just change names, titles or whatever into something random. If you provide data for say, 4 pages and sketch how that would appear in the report based on your sample, it "might" be there is an easier approach to the whole thing. It's after 10pm here so I won't pick this up again for a little while but if you get no further, post sample dummy data et and I'll see what I can do

Comment: Hi Alan, I had to take a break from this project, but I've completely re-phrased my question to include dummy data and hopefully explain the goal more clearly. If you're still willing to help, please reread the question as it has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your sample data and reworked the query to give the data I would use if I need to do this. It may not suit your setup exactly but it should be close enough to revise.

I basically output page numbers and row and column numbers from the dataset query that we can then use in a Matrix control.

Here's the modified query..

```
DECLARE @Badges TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Badges VALUES
  (100001, 'Anna')
, (100002, 'Bart')
, (100003, 'Cathy')
, (100004, 'Daniel')
, (100005, 'Ericka')
, (100006, 'Fred')
, (100007, 'Gwen')
, (100008, 'Harry')
, (100009, 'Idita')
, (100010, 'Joshi')
, (100011, 'Katie')
, (100012, 'Leo')
, (100013, 'Manuela')
, (100014, 'Nando')
, (100015, 'Olga')
, (100016, 'Park')
, (100017, 'Quang')
, (100018, 'Rhys')
, (100019, 'Sarina')
, (100020, 'Theo')
, (100021, 'Udeyume')
, (100022, 'Victor')
, (100023, 'Wynona')
, (100024, 'Xavier');

WITH t (rN, PageN, RowN, ColN, ID, Name)
AS (
SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Name) AS rN
        , ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Name) - 1) / 6) +1 AS PageN
        , ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Name) - 1) % 3) + 1 AS RowN
        , ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Name) - 1) /3) % 2 AS ColN
        , b.*
    FROM @Badges AS b
) 

SELECT PageN, 1 AS OddEven, RowN, ColN, [Name] as  Caption from t 
UNION 
SELECT PageN, 2, RowN, CASE ColN WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, CAST([ID] as varchar(50)) as  Caption from t ;
```

This give the following results (not all shown)

[image]

I created a new report and added a Matrix. I dragged the RowN field to the rows placeholder, ColN to col placeholder and Caption to the data placeholder. I then added a parent group grouped by PageN **and** OddEven. In the group properties for the "PageN" Row Group I set the sort to both PageN and OddEven and set a pagebreak between each instance.

For illustration I've left a few rows and column in that are not required, I also added a column inside the column group (the grey cell) to act as padding which might be useful for aligning things.

The report design looks like this
[image]

The final output looks like this

Page 1:
[image]

Page 2:
[image]

Page 3:
[image]

Page 4:
[image]

and so on...

Once the redundant rows and columns are removed, all pages should appear in the same position on each page.

Comment: When you say, "I then added a parent group grouped by PageN **and** OddEven. In the group properties for the 'PageN' Row Group I set the sort to both PageN and OddEven and set a pagebreak between each instance." Do you mean you have 1 parent row group using PageN (on RowN) and then in the Sorting for that group, you've added 2 Columns to sort by: PageN and "Then by" OddEven? Or did you create a combination sort of some kind using an Expression? Can you clarify?

Comment: The "PageN" row group, groups by `PageN` and `OddEven`. It also sorts by `PageN` and `OddEven`. If this does not help, let me know and I'll post a screenshot of the RowGroup properties later tonight.

Comment: Since the ID would need to print on the back of the wearer's badge, it will need to go in the opposite column on the page following the wearer's name. See Gwen in your last screenshot. Her name is on the left-hand side on page 3. Her ID is 100007, so it should be on the right-hand side on page 4 instead of the left. If it stays on the left-hand side like her Name on page 3, then it will end up on the back of Joshi's badge on page 4.

Comment: Simple to fix, just change the ColN in the final SQL statement to `CASE ColN WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` to reverse the order of the ID data columns. I've updated the answer to match the new query ouput